# Having problem displaying my image in second VC from first VC! Instead the second VC turns into a new camera view

Tags: ios, swift, camera

When I try to display an image that's supposed to be taken in first VC in second VC but instead the second VC turns into a camera view similar to first VC, which I don't want. I also get the error "reason: '*** -[AVCaptureSession addInput:] Multiple audio/video AVCaptureInputs are not currently supported'
*** First throw call stack:
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb) "

Have tried to change my code with new camera codes but still got the same problem so I watched old questions and a little bit from Youtube tutorials but that didn't help me either.

**FirstViewController**

```
let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
var previewLayer:CALayer!

var captureDevice:AVCaptureDevice!

var takePhoto = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
     prepareCamera()
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

}


func prepareCamera() {
    captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.photo

    let availableDevices = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: AVMediaType.video, position: .back).devices
    captureDevice = availableDevices.first
    beginSession()


}

func beginSession () {
    do {
        let captureDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)

        captureSession.addInput(captureDeviceInput)

    }catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }


    let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
    self.previewLayer = previewLayer
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(self.previewLayer)
    self.previewLayer.frame = self.view.layer.frame
    captureSession.startRunning()

    let dataOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
    dataOutput.videoSettings = [(kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as NSString):NSNumber(value:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)] as [String : Any]

    dataOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true

    if captureSession.canAddOutput(dataOutput) {
        captureSession.addOutput(dataOutput)
    }

    captureSession.commitConfiguration()


    let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.brianadvent.captureQueue")
    dataOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: queue)

}

@IBAction func takePhoto(_ sender: Any) {
    takePhoto = true

}

func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {

    if takePhoto {
        takePhoto = false

        if let image = self.getImageFromSampleBuffer(buffer: sampleBuffer) {

            let photoVC =  UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:  nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PhotoVC") as! Viewcontroller2

            photoVC.takenPhoto = image

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.present(photoVC, animated: true, completion: {
                    self.stopCaptureSession()
                })

            }
        }


    }
}


func getImageFromSampleBuffer (buffer:CMSampleBuffer) -> UIImage? {
    if let pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(buffer) {
        let ciImage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer)
        let context = CIContext()

        let imageRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixelBuffer), height: CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixelBuffer))

        if let image = context.createCGImage(ciImage, from: imageRect) {
            return UIImage(cgImage: image, scale: UIScreen.main.scale, orientation: .right)
        }

    }

    return nil
}

func stopCaptureSession () {
    self.captureSession.stopRunning()

    if let inputs = captureSession.inputs as? [AVCaptureDeviceInput] {
        for input in inputs {
            self.captureSession.removeInput(input)
        }
    }

}
```

**SecondViewController**

```
var takenPhoto:UIImage?

@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let availableImage = takenPhoto {
        imageView.image = availableImage
    }


}


@IBAction func goBack(_ sender: Any) {

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add additional code, don't add it as a comment. Is the code shown from your first or second view controller?  How do you move from the first to second view controller?  Show that code

Comment: Have changed it now, thanks for noticing, upper is first VC and the on below is second VC @Paulw11